# overflow: visible link not clickable when next to absolute position element

Tags: html, css

I have two absolutely positioned div elements, which are placed next to each other.  The first div element has `overflow: visible` and a link with long content which flows on top of the neighboring div element.  I am trying to click on the link from the neighboring div, with no luck- in Chrome and Firefox.  This works in IE9.
Some code example will explain what I am trying to do-

```
<div>
  <a href="#">Reeeeeeeeeeeeeaallllllly Looooon Liiink Teeeext</a>
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>​
```

And the style sheet:

```
div{
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 80px;
border: 2px solid;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 1;
}
.two{
left:82px;
}
a{
z-index: 2;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzSwL/1/

Any suggestions?  I thought z-index might help, but no.  The link text is also not selectable when the mouse is over the second div.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Actually my scenario is more complex then I let on, since I didn't realize where the answers would go.  Pointer-events looks like the cleanest solution, but unfortunately I can not use it since all the divs might have links in them.

A more realistic jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzSwL/6/

Just to explain what I am trying to get at- I am making a schedule app with an hour grid with a lot of positioned divs next to each other.  Each div could have a link in it.  The width of the link is the length of the appointment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by setting `pointer-events:none;` for class .two

The pointer wants to focus on the top div, but if you tell it not to, it will go to the div that is behind.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzSwL/2/

Comment: Then apply a class to the link with `{ pointer-events: all; }`. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/yzSwL/7/

Comment: Nice! Thanks.  Never heard of pointer-events before.  I guess that explains why it works in IE9 and not the others.

Answer (score 1):

you will have problems using `pointer-events` in IE 9 and below and also Opera.

I have slightly restructured your HTML CSS  http://jsfiddle.net/GVL5e/

Comment: Actually it's already working in IE9 for precisely that reason, no support for pointer-events.

Comment: That's an excellent solution. I used your approach to bring to front a relative positioned div on an absolute position stretched image.  That div had all it's link and button elements non-clickable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This rule has no effect:

```
a{
z-index: 2;
}
```

It's not the `a` that's positioned, but its parent `div`. [`z-index` only applies to positioned elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)

What you should do instead is this:

```
div{
    ...
    z-index: 2;
}
.two{
    ...
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzSwL/4/

Also note that even if you were to add `position: absolute` to the `a` to make `z-index` work for it, it would *still* not go on top of `.two`. That would only cause it to get positioned on top of other elements inside its positioned parent `div` (its stacking context).

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution but you have to change the style:

1. Do not force your divs to have fixed width
2. Set `overflow:hidden;`
3. Remove `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: I need all of those CSS rules for layout.  I want to maintain the same layout just make the link clickable.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you assign same z-index to both DIV's.

Instead, try to assign a lower z-index to the second DIV.

```
div{
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 80px;
border: 2px solid;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 10;
}
.two{
left:82px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```